# MySQL add column with null significantly longer than with default of ""

Tags: mysql

I tried running the following command on a MySQL server and many times it never completes:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable`
    ADD COLUMN my column varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL NULL;
```

I had to restart the MySQL several times to get it to complete.

When I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable`
    ADD COLUMN my column varchar(255) DEFAULT "" NULL;
```

It completes much faster (in a matter of seconds) and works 100% of the time.

Database is 15 Gig and there are about 6 instances of the database running on cloud server with 32 gigs of ram.  The mySQL version is below:

```
innodb_version  5.6.31
protocol_version    10
slave_type_conversions  
version 5.6.31
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
```

Comment: Depends on the table. Can you give details about the table? Size, column count, indexes etc. Btw, `nullable` value is a performance killer for an indexed column, because mysql handles null values different than others according to their docs.

Comment: Since `NULL` is the "natural" default, why explicitly specify it?

Comment: why `DEFAULT NULL NULL` and not only `DEFAULT NULL`? You can define two default values on MySQL?

Comment: Which mysql engine you are using??

Comment: The first NULL sets the default and the second NULL is a flag that allows the column to be nullable.  DEFAULT "" NULL; implies the default is empty string but the column can be set to null.

Comment: That column is not going to be indexed, there are other existing indexes on the table.  Table has about 1500 rows and many tables in the database have foreign keys pointing to this table.

Comment: @TrevorFoley - Thank You! I didn't know that. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: show engines gave: `InnoDB DEFAULT Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys `

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* `DEFAULT NULL` part. It's the default behavior for NULL columns.

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable`
ADD COLUMN 'my column' varchar(255) NULL ;
```

is enough